# What is the best vectorization method here?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am wondering what would be the best way to vectorize the following formula:

```
c= Sum(u(i)*<u(i),y>/v(i) )
```

`<.,.>` means dot product of two matrix.

let say we have a matrix `K= U*Diag(w)*U^-1` (`w` and `u` are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix `k` of size `nxn`) . and `y` is a vector of size `n`.

so if :

```
k=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,7,8]])
y=np.array([1,4,5])
w,u=np.linalg.eigh(k)
```

then :

```
w=array([ -2.02599523,   0.47346124,  13.552534  ])


u=array([[-0.18897996,  0.95770742,  0.21698634],
        [ 0.82245177,  0.03363605,  0.5678395 ],
       [-0.53652554, -0.28577109,  0.79402471]])
```

This is how I implemented it:

```
uDoty=np.dot(u,y)
div=np.divide(y,w)

div=np.divide(uDoty,w)
r=np.tile(div,(len(u),1))
a=u*r.T
c=sum(a)
```

But it actually It doesn't look nice to me.So is there any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a mathematical meaning of this? Maybe numpy/scipy has a built-in function to calculate `c` from `k`.

Comment: yes. actually it's kind of the same thing as solving the equation A*x=b , but as I need to play with this formula for other stuff I need to implement this formula.Actually I solve the equation by numpy.solve() and then compare it with this result.

Comment: You could also try `np.einsum`, of course the division is not possible with it, you would have to multiply the reciprocal (but `np.dot` alone is faster then einsum with blas). Do you really need `np.tile`? Numpy broadcasts arrays automatically, so its enough to add a 1-dimension axis normally. And what is `temp` for?

Comment: I have not used this function before. I should check how to use it! I  used np.tile because it was the only solution that came into my mind! sorry about "temp" , it was leftover from previews code. I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `np.tile` with some broadcasting:

```
U = np.dot(u, y)
d = U/w
a = u*d[:,None]
c = a.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped alot. Is it also the optimize solution?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean is it the fastest way to compute the solution ? because my matrix can be very large !

Comment: I don't know whether it's the fastest, but it's the one most readable one, and there's not much left to simplify. You may want to skip some of the temporaries, like calculating `(u*d[:,None]).sum()` directly, but I don't think it'll change much.